# Staggered synthetic control with not yet treated donors using Stata's allsynth

Tags: statistics, stata, economics

## The problem

I am trying to create a microeconometric model in Stata in which I use staggered synthetic control (in the fashion of Ben-Michael et al., 2021; Cao & Lu, 2019) to estimate the effect of the establishment of Amazon centers in Italy (much like Wiltshire, 2021, who made the `allsynth` command).

The key difference with all these models is that I am trying to use not yet treated units as donors, as I have some trouble using the full set of Italian municipalities because they have key differences with the ones Amazon establishes itself into (a strategy already done in Chava et al., 2022).

The `allsynth` package however returned an error to me whenever I tried to use my data, as it said that the donors contained a treatment period (of course! they are not-yet-treated units, not controls).

Thus, I modified the code by setting the year of operations (year where the units are treated) to missing for the donors, and generated a panel variable that distinguishes the units as I like (it contains the commuting zone, the specific municipality, and a dummy for treated or not-yet-treated).

Still, I got an error, some variable is 'already defined'. Setting trace on, it's the year of operations, but I don't understand why.

Does anyone have experience with `allsynth`, staggered synthetic control, not-yet-treated control strategies? Is the thing I am trying to do in any way novel, so I should beware of the statistics and not expect any code to work fine? Thank you for any answer or discussion.

P.S. In case anybody is asking, I have already done a Callaway Sant'Anna, that works fine, I am just trying to get to the same results using another method and to get a causal heterogeneity measure.

## My code:

```
egen synthpanel = group(cid id open_yet)
preserve
    xtset synthpanel year 
    drop if year < 2010 
    drop if year_op == 2011 
    replace year_op = . if year < year_op 
allsynth p_wages, bcorrect(merge) keep(synth_amazon, replace) stacked(trunits(open_yet) trperiods(year_op) clear figure (classic bcorrect))
restore
```

## What happens in Stata (error between asterisks):

```
 preserve

.         xtset synthpanel year 

Panel variable: synthpanel (unbalanced)
 Time variable: year, 2006 to 2020
         Delta: 1 unit

.         drop if year < 2010 
(3,994 observations deleted)

.         drop if year_op == 2011 
(103 observations deleted)

.         replace year_op = . if year < year_op 
(7,750 real changes made, 7,750 to missing)

. allsynth p_wages, bcorrect(merge) keep(synth_amazon, replace) stacked(trunits(
> open_yet) trperiods(year_op) clear figure (classic bcorrect))
**variable __00000D already defined**
r(110);

end of do-file
```

## The part of the trace in which the error is explained (I sadly don't understand any of this, the whole trace is several pages long so I don't post it here):

```
 east 2 donor pool (untreated) units"
    exit 198
    }
    }
  - if "`_Entry'" == "trperiods" {
  = if "trperiods" == "trperiods" {
  - qui gen `_trP' = `s2'
  = qui gen __00000D = year_op
**variable __00000D already defined**
    qui recode `_trP' (0=.)
    local trP "`s2'"
    }
```

Comment: You provided  a lot of information and may be lucky here to find someone who knows about this, including recognising all those name (date) references.  Your chances of getting good advice are much, much higher on Statalist. The answer so far as I can guess may be anything from you found a bug through what you want makes sense but is not supported to anywhere beyond.